# Is there a way to use Powershell Stopwatch as a counter from a predetermined time?

Tags: powershell, timer, count, counter

I'd been looking for ages to find a way to create a second by second timer/counter using powershell, but using a historical date/time from which to start from.

All the examples I found were using stopwatch (great), but this doesn't seem to work with a "pre-loaded" date/time. Only the current time.

After pulling ideas from a few places I got a working script, but was curious to know if there was a better way of doing this?

```
write-host "Started at $(get-date)"

for ($t=1; $t -le 300; $t++) {
$date = Get-Date
$datediff =(NEW-TIMESPAN -Start $StartDate -End $date).ToString()
$datediff | OUT-FILE "C:\Temp\ChronoDiff.txt"
    sleep 1
}
```

Comment: [1] `Get-Date` is rather slow, so it will add a noticeable amount of delay to your loop. use `[datetime]::Now` instead. [2] you are getting _negative_ times. [*grin*] you likely otta reverse your datetime math. [3] `New-TimeSpan` is not needed. just subtract the two datetime items from each other directly. this will also remove a detectable delay. [4] you are overwriting your output file ever time. why? not only do file writes slow things down considerably, but it makes more sense to write that file after the fact.

Comment: [5] the `for` loop is slower than the `foreach` loop. for small counts it makes no difference, but you may want to go with the more efficient loop. [6] there is no need to use the `$Date` or `$DateDiff` variables. simply do the datetime math in one step like this ... >>> `([datetime]::Now - $StartDate).ToString()`

Comment: Thanks for the replies. re: "you are overwriting your output file ever time. why?" I'm currently using a freeware tool called Snaz to do the count to output to file (monitored and displayed by another application), but there's a wicked time drift on Snaz it which make it inaccurate over a period of time more than a couple of hours. This script was me trying to make a counter which was time as accurate as possible, but I didn't mind skipping a second every 30s or so to keep it accurate

Comment: thank you for the "why" of item [4] and why the inaccuracy is acceptable. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

It's a good solution.
And if you are looking for something like StopWatch function with input property (your specific start date / time), put your code into the function with StopWatch name.

```
    function StopWatch ([datetime]$StartDate) {
        do {
            write-host "$((New-TimeSpan $StartDate (get-date)).tostring())`r" -NoNewline
            sleep 1
        } while ($true)
    }

    C:\PS>StopWatch 1.1.2019
    C:\PS>StopWatch '1.1.2019 12:20'
```

Answer (score 0):

here's an alternate way to get things done. [*grin*] what it does ...

- uses `[datetime]::Now` to get the current time
  this is noticeably faster than `Get-Date`.
- bundles the code into a function with a standard name format
- uses `foreach` instead of `for`
  the 1st is faster than the 2nd since it does the test ONCE and then simply iterates thru the resulting range instead of testing every pass.
- uses direct datetime math instead of the slower `New-TimeSpan`.
- subtracts the start time from the current time
  your code gives you negative time intervals. i presume you really want "how long has it been?" instead of "how far in the past is the start date?".
- uses the full name of the `Start-Sleep` cmdlet
  it's good to use the full name of any cmdlet/function/parameter so that you have easy-to-scan code.

here's the code ...

```
function Get-TimerSeconds
    {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [datetime]
        $StartDate = [datetime]::Now,

        [int]
        $TotalSeconds = 10
        )

    begin {}

    process
        {
        foreach ($Second in 1..$TotalSeconds)
            {
            ([datetime]::Now - $StartDate).ToString()
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
            }
        }

    end {}

    }
```

truncated output with `Get-TimerSeconds` ...

```
00:00:00
00:00:01.0170000
...
00:00:08.1150000
00:00:09.1290000
```

truncated output with `Get-TimerInfo -StartDate '2019-11-01 21:31:41' -TotalSeconds 15` ...

```
3.13:23:06.4170000
3.13:23:07.4320000
...
3.13:23:19.6000000
3.13:23:20.6150000
```